# Is shorting and removing independent sources related to superposition theorem?

Tags: circuit-theory

I was looking at a derivation of differential gain for a BJT differential amplifier.

Along the derivation the power supply and the tail current sources are nulled. I mean the Vcc is shorted to ground and the tail current source removed.

What allows one to do that? Is it related to system being LTI or superposition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You take the circuit as a whole and you solve for bias, using one set of approximations (Vbe = 0.6V, Hfe is constant, etc.).  Then you use the solution to that problem as inputs to the problem of finding the parameters of a linearized model (usually a hybrid-pi, but there are others), meaning in effect that you're generating a whole *different* set of approximations.  At that point, you have a LTI model of your system, and you can zero out any DC sources and treat all signals as perturbations around that operating point.

What allows you to do that is that you made a model of the circuit which is a LTI system.  The circuit itself isn't LTI -- but your model is, and you can play all of the LTI tricks on it to find answers.